# Help me test my electricity usage monitor?

Tags: electrical, energy-efficiency, testing

I just got one of [these](http://www.p3international.com/products/P4400.html); I love it and it seems accurate. But I would like to check its accuracy.

Can anyone think of an appliance with very predictable constant power consumption that I could use to test it?

If not, can anyone think of other ways to test it? I was thinking I could get a second one, and either test them side-by-side with similar appliances or plug one into the other and see how close they are. Or maybe I could hook it to a large appliance and compare the power use to the increase in power consumption on my main meter. Not sure....

Edit: h/t @Harper - Reinstate Monica maybe I can use this method: https://youtu.be/xCVnW_Ou470?t=107

Thanks!

---

Update: I tested my Kill-a-Watt with the following devices:

18W portable fan with single setting - Kill-a-Watt says 17.6
120V 8A portable drill, trigger all the way down running in the air - Kill-a-Watt says much less than 960
1500W electric kettle - Kill-a-Watt says 1487

The drill is the outlier. Based on the comments this seems normal for electric motors not encountering much resistance.

Comment: They work. No need to go out of your way questioning it.

Comment: https://youtu.be/xCVnW_Ou470?t=107

Comment: do you want to measure apparent power or real power? (there's different methods for both). Some meters are pretty accurate for VA, but not W. 
That said, I would just use a DMM to verify some of the meter's measurements and trust the rest.

Comment: @dandavis good question, I'm not sure but I'll get back to you when I know.

Comment: @dandavis I think I want real power, because as I understand it from my googling real power represents what I am getting from the wall.

Comment: We get voltage from the wall, not power, which comes from _consuming_ the voltage to generate a current. If you want agreement with your utility meter, go for real power (for now), if you're running a generator, watch out for apparent power to avoid over-load. A high-precision and accurate way of measuring dc-equiv consumption is to briefly power a 1000 ohm 50-watt ceramic power resistor from the wall, and measure the voltage across it with a true RMS DMM. Where v is the reading, watts will be (v/1000)*v, so compare that to the usage monitor. Oh; measure the resistance and sub that for 1000.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it's expected that a drill will not use its full power just spinning in the air.  Higher power draw will occur when it encounters a lot of resistance to turning, such as when drilling through a difficult material.  This is true of all electric motors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a portable resistance heater?

[image]

Comment: power draw depends on voltage though, which fluctuates throughout the day, limiting the accuracy of this test.

Comment: @dandavis, voltage should not fluctuate much throughout the day in most developed countries -- there's people working very hard to make sure of that.  And you can always measure the voltage at the same time, and correct for any differences.

Comment: @NateS. I'd like to consider my area "developed", but I measure several volts of variation ~(117-124), enough to obscure potential errors and prevent validating the 0.2% claim of the kill-a-watt. Yes, V can be measured alongside, but the KAW's accumulation and W screen won't do that when used intuitively.

Comment: @dandavis, fair enough, yeah, if you want to measure to an accuracy of under a percent, using a resistor of a known value like you mentioned in the comments would be the way to go, since I very much doubt the nameplate rating of a heater like this is any more accurate than that.  If you turn that into an answer, I'll +1 it.

Comment: The KAW is constantly making the measurments of actual voltage and actual amperage and the time (thus phase) relationship between them, and the results at the VA, W and kWh screens all reflect that to a degree of accuracy that's outstanding for the price. When I've had everything running through a KAW (early construction, small enough loads that could be the case) and a smart meter, they agree quite nicely. Either accept that it works, or go get $3000 worth of power analyzer to validate your $20 KAW.

Comment: @NateS Like to add, if his purpose is to check for his utility billing, the power company charges for power consumed at the METER, not the outlets, so he gets charged for heat lost in his walls in the wiring. (his or hers)
That being said, he could ignore compensating for voltage, and just use one volt reading at the meter (ie, at his panel, or an unloaded circuit on the same pole).
Not being critical, I just realized that from a bill perspective, he should use the meter source voltage.
OH, guess he would have to compensate UPWARDS, since the monitor only knows the voltage where it is at.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's only good for 1875 watts, I'd be plugging in my toaster oven or a 1400 watt hair dryer. Both of those appliances will state the watts or amperage and you could compare it to your readout. Make sure you read your display before the appliances start cycling on and off... set them on high.

Comment: Set them on high and give them a minute or two to reach steady state. You could use an infrared or instant-read thermometer to monitor this.

Comment: listed current is rarely exact, usually it's a worse-case scenario.

Comment: @dandavis it often assumes 125V.

Comment: @dandavis  No meters are exact either.  The line voltage from the power company changes constantly so the amps would too.

Comment: I could just as easily have set this as the answer, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

try it with an incandescent lightbulb  100W if you have one...